# Проблема с шрифтом редактора в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Скачала Intellij IDEA, а после установки вот такая фигня. Пишет некоторые слова через тире в ненужном месте. Подскажите, как это убрать
[image: https://cs7054.vk.me/c540101/v540101956/409af/D2IK_W-Nr0I.jpg]

Comment: через пробел может?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте поменять шрифт редактора:

`Ctrl+Alt+S` => в меню слева найдите `Editor/Colors & Fonts/Font` => поменяйте `Primary Font`.

Если список выбора шрифта неактивен, вначале нажмите `Save As...` возле активной темы оформления, и задайте свое имя.